# Get the last node of a Google maps XML file

Tags: javascript, xml, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I have been playing around with Google maps API v3 because v2 is deprecated and no longer works for my site

Instead of displaying every pointer in the xml file on the map, I want to display the current marker that would be relevant to that page.  I have an events page so I want to show info about the event and display a map just for that event taken from the xml file.

I have it all working except I need to specify an id in the url which is what I need to do but what if there is no id set in the url.

Say my url would be www.mysite.com/events.php that won't show a map because there is no id but if I use www.mysite.com/events.php?id=1 the map will show

what I need is to determine if an id is in the url and if not, find the last marker of the xml file and show that instead as it will be the most current

Here is the google code along with my additions that check if the id in the url is present

```
   function load() {
          var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(50.618438, -3.420304),
            zoom: 13,
            mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
          });
          var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

          // Change this depending on the name of your PHP file
          downloadUrl("results.xml", function(data) {
            var xml = data.responseXML;
            var the_id = gup('id');

            var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
            var last = markers.length-1;

            for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
                if (markers[i].hasAttribute('id')) {
                    //if there is, test its value
                    if (markers[i].getAttribute('id') == the_id) {
                          var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
                          var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
                          var type = markers[i].getAttribute("type");
                          var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
                              parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
                              parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
                          var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address;
                          var icon = customIcons[type] || {};
                          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                            map: map,
                            position: point,
                            icon: icon.icon,
                            shadow: icon.shadow
                          });

                        bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
                     }
                     else {
                         var name = markers[last].getAttribute("name");
                          var address = markers[last].getAttribute("address");
                          var type = markers[last].getAttribute("type");
                          var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
                              parseFloat(markers[last].getAttribute("lat")),
                              parseFloat(markers[last].getAttribute("lng")));
                          var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address;
                          var icon = customIcons[type] || {};
                          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                            map: map,
                            position: point,
                            icon: icon.icon,
                            shadow: icon.shadow
                          });

                        bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
                     }

                }
            }
          });
        }
```

I have added an else so it should replace the i in the for-loop with the last xml marker but it doesn't work

and here is the function which gets the id from the url

```
function gup( name ) {
  name = name.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");
  var regexS = "[\\?&]"+name+"=([^&#]*)";
  var regex = new RegExp( regexS );
  var results = regex.exec( window.location.href );
  if( results == null )
    return "";
  else
    return results[1];
}
```

I think I need to check if the id is present, if not, get the last marker.

Comment: The ID of the last marker would be `markers[markers.length-1].getAttribute('id')` - but that can't be your question, or can it?

Comment: I think i know what you mean but say i have 10 markers, i need to get the last marker after the else so it should be markers[9] obvisously with the -1

Comment: If you have 10 markers, then `markers.length` will be 10. This means you need to use the -1 to retrieve the last one.

Comment: @Tomalak, he has `var lgth = markers.length-1` and he uses `markers[lgth]`, so he should be OK in that regard. @AdRock that variable name would make more sense if you called it `last` instead of `lgth` since `length` is the number of items (e.g. 10).

Answer (score 1):

Ah... for one thing, your "else" clause is at the wrong level (and attached to the wrong if).
It's getting exercised once *for every marker that has an id*, because it's inside the for loop. At the minimum, you should move the else out of the for loop.

But the `for` loop is unnecessary too. Instead of looping through the marker elements checking which one has the right id, use `getElementById(id)`:

```
 var the_id = gup('id');
 var respDoc = data.responseXML.documentElement
 var the_marker = respDoc.getElementById(the_id);
 // If the_id is '' then there will be no such marker, and the_marker will be
 // null, which is "falsy".
 if (!the_marker) {
   var markers = respDoc.getElementsByTagName("marker");
   // check whether there are any markers.
   if (markers.length < 1) return; // avoid errors
   the_marker = markers[markers.length - 1];
 }
 // Now do what you need to with the_marker.getAttribute("name") etc.
 // This is just your code, with markers[i] replaced by the_marker:
 var name = the_marker.getAttribute("name");
 var address = the_marker.getAttribute("address");
 var type = the_marker.getAttribute("type");
 var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
   parseFloat(the_marker.getAttribute("lat")),
   parseFloat(the_marker.getAttribute("lng")));
 var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address;
 var icon = customIcons[type] || {};
 var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: point,
    icon: icon.icon,
    shadow: icon.shadow
 });

 bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
```

(Untested.)

Finally, I noticed that the gup() you're using is looking at window.location.href, the URL of the current web page. That *is* what you want, right? OK, just checking...

Comment: If this doesn't fix the problem, you may need to be more specific about "it doesn't work". Does it work when there is an id? or never? When it doesn't work, what actually happens?

Comment: Can you please edit my code so i can test it?  Where you have the comment // Now do what you need to with the_marker.getAttribute("name") etc, I need to do everything in the inner most if where i set some vars for the map

Comment: Well, OK... see edited answer in a few minutes. I'm just copying your code and replacing markers[x] with the_marker.

Comment: Tried your suggestion and i get a blank page both with and without an id.  you can see the result here http://www.jackgodfrey.org.uk/test2.html?id=10

Comment: @jack - when I go to that link I get a 404, rather than a blank page. So I can't see your test. If you're getting a completely blank page, it suggests the map is not loading; maybe there's a syntax error. Did you check the javascript console? Were you seeing a blank page with your earlier code (with an id in the URL), or is this a new problem? If a map is appearing, you might try using alert() or Firebug (javascript debugger) to find out the value of `the_id` and `the_marker` after you attempt to compute them.